# XML Parsing in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

After some operation i get the bewlow xml response from the server. Now i need to get the data from these tags. Please guide me how can i get that.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Result xmlns="GlobalPayments">0</Result>
    <RespMSG xmlns="GlobalPayments">Approved</RespMSG>
    <Message xmlns="GlobalPayments">AP</Message>
    <AuthCode xmlns="GlobalPayments">01245F</AuthCode>
    <PNRef xmlns="GlobalPayments">170015964</PNRef>
    <HostCode xmlns="GlobalPayments">002</HostCode>
    <GetCVResultTXT xmlns="GlobalPayments">Service Not Requested</GetCVResultTXT>
    <GetCommercialCard xmlns="GlobalPayments">True</GetCommercialCard>
    <ExtData xmlns="GlobalPayments">CardType=Visa,BatchNum=0202&lt;BatchNum&gt;0202&lt;/BatchNum&gt;&lt;ReceiptData&gt;&lt;MID&gt;87228799&lt;/MID&gt;&lt;Trans_Id&gt;283220167525&lt;/Trans_Id&gt;&lt;Val_Code&gt;52ND&lt;/Val_Code&gt;&lt;/ReceiptData&gt;</ExtData>

</Response>
```

I am using the below code and the Issue is the  **XmlPullParser.START_TAG:** gives the whole tags available into the xml not required one tag.

```
 package com.parsing_new;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

    import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

class Response
{

 public String Reslt;
 public String Respmsg;
 public String Msg;
 public String Auth;
 public String Pnref;
 public String Host;
 public String Getcv;
 public String Getcom;
 public String Ext;


}
public class ParsingActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_parsing);
  XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
  try {
   pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
   XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
       InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp.xml");
          parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
             parser.setInput(in_s, null);
             parseXML(parser);
  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
 {
  ArrayList<Response> responses = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Response currentProduct = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
           String name = null;
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                 responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    Log.d("Result", name);

                    if (name == "Response"){
                        currentProduct = new Response();
                    }  else if (currentProduct != null){
                        if (name == "Result"){
                            currentProduct.Reslt = parser.nextText();
                        } else if (name == "RespMSG"){
                         currentProduct.Respmsg = parser.nextText();
                        } else if (name == "Message"){
                            currentProduct.Msg= parser.nextText();
                        }
                            else if (name == "AuthCode"){
                             currentProduct.Auth = parser.nextText();
                        }
                            else if (name == "PNRef "){
                             currentProduct.Pnref = parser.nextText();
                            }
                            else if (name == "HostCode "){
                             currentProduct.Host = parser.nextText();
                            }
                            else if (name == "GetCVResultTXT "){
                             currentProduct.Getcv = parser.nextText();
                            }
                            else if (name == "GetCommercialCard"){
                             currentProduct.Getcom = parser.nextText();
                            }
                              else if (name == "ExtData"){
                                  currentProduct.Ext = parser.nextText();
                              }
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    Log.d("Resultend", name);
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Response") && currentProduct != null){
                     responses.add(currentProduct);
                     //Log.d("tag",responses.toString());
                    }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
        printProducts(responses);
 }
 private void printProducts(ArrayList<Response> responses)
 {
  String content = "";
  Iterator<Response> it = responses.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
   Response currProduct  = it.next();
   content = content + "\n\n\nResult :" +  currProduct.Reslt + "\n";
   content = content + "Respmsg :" +  currProduct.Respmsg + "\n";
   content = content + "Msg :" +  currProduct.Msg + "\n";
   content = content + "Auth :" +  currProduct.Auth + "\n";
   content = content + "Pn :" +  currProduct.Pnref + "\n";
   content = content + "Host :" +  currProduct.Host + "\n";
   content = content + "CV :" +  currProduct.Getcv + "\n";
   content = content + "Com :" +  currProduct.Getcom + "\n";
   content = content + "Ext :" +  currProduct.Ext+ "\n";
  }
  TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  display.setText(content);
 }

}
```

Please guide me how can we do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Log.e("ParsingActivity",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.. parseXML.................." );
        ArrayList<Response> responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Response currentProduct = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType){
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                String name = parser.getName();
                Log.e("ParsingActivity", " >>>>>.... Tag name   = " + name);
                if (name.equals("Response")) {
                    currentProduct = new Response();
                } else if (name.equals("Result")) {
                    currentProduct.Reslt = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("RespMSG")) {
                    currentProduct.Respmsg = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("Message")) {
                    currentProduct.Msg = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("AuthCode")) {
                    currentProduct.Auth = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("PNRef ")) {
                    currentProduct.Pnref = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("HostCode ")) {
                    currentProduct.Host = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("GetCVResultTXT ")) {
                    currentProduct.Getcv = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("GetCommercialCard")) {
                    currentProduct.Getcom = parser.nextText();
                } else if (name.equals("ExtData")) {
                    currentProduct.Ext = parser.nextText();
                }

                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("Response")) {
                    responses.add(currentProduct);
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        printProducts(responses);
    }
```